# Click on HTML element using JS

Tags: javascript, html, click, mouse

So basically I have a web page, and a couple of HTML buttons on it. On one of them I'd like to perform a mouse click. I know this button's class name, so basically I want to click on it by its class name. I know how to get the class name but I don't know how to click on this element, maybe there is a click function or something I don't know anything about.

I'm using

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-xs truncate');
element.Click();
```

but i don't know what to do next, how to perform the click, can you help me with that?

`element.Click();` method doesn't work, I get the error:

> element.Click is not a function

Comment: element.Click(); doesn't work

Comment: NB. `click()` is not the same as `Click()`: JS is case sensitive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there is a possibility that there are multiple elements with the class name `hidden-xs truncate` javascript automatically places the elements in an array.

you can auto click the button like this:

`document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-xs truncate")[0].click();`

or

`var element = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-xs truncate");
element[0].click();`

note: the [0] gets the first index of the array, if there are multiple elements with the classes given it will perform a click only on the first element if you did [1] it would be the second and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to add an id to the button that would probably help as getting the position in the array of the button is less than ideal - someone else could come along and add a button above yours and then the click event will be on the wrong one.

In that case, you'd do

`var element = window.document.getElementById('my-id');`

then as before

`element.click();`